# Vacuum polarization in QCD and gluon bubbles

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, vacuum, feynman-diagrams, gluons

In analogy to QED, the following Feynman diagram is a diagram contributing to the vacuum polarization effect, leading to anti-screening, asymptotic freedom and running of the strong coupling constant. It can also be interpreted as a correction to the propagator of the gluon.

[image]

(Of course, there's no true analogy to this diagram in QED because photons do not couple to themselves, and here we make use of the existence of a 3-gluon vertex. In QED we would have a fermion-antifermion pair instead of bosons in the loop, similar to a gluon going to fermion-antifermion and back in QCD.)

My question now is about **the following diagram** which has a 4-gluon vertex:

[image]

**Does this also contribute to vacuum polarization and the effects it entails? Or is it something conceptually different?** (It seems different because we don't have the splitting of one object into two and back.)

*(PS: Feel free to add more meaningful tags and correct any statements in the above which are wrong.)*

Comment: This term really is zero, and this can be proved by the dimensional regularization method.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is another diagram that contributes to "vacuum polarization", also called self-energy. If you want to make a consistent calculation of the self-energy in perturbation theory, you need to include the two diagrams that you mention, plus the diagram where the gluon splits into $\bar{q}q$, plus, depending on your gauge choice any ghost diagrams.

Comment: Even though technically you must take it into account, it turns out that in four spacetime dimensions its contribution is zero. For more details see P&S page 524.